# Best method for custom cursor image on a website

Tags: javascript, css, cursor

What is the best method to generate a custom cursor image for use in conjunction with a CSS/HTML5 website? Flash is not an option in this case, and if it's possible I'd prefer to be able to use CSS instead of reverting to Javascript. If Javascript is the only viable option, which solution requires the least amount of libraries to be loaded while being compatible with all browsers? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the CSS property `cursor`, you can define the type or an url to the image you want to use:

```
cursor: url('image.gif'), pointer;
```

IE6 supports only images in format .cur or .ani

Comment: Apparently Opera does not support the cursor:url cursors, so they'll only see the normal pointer.

Comment: I've seen in older versions didn't work, but I don't really know if in the latest

Comment: I thought I was using the latest. *checks* Yeah, 11.60 on Win7 and... it does not work, as far as I can tell.